# ServiceNow : Jelly Error

Tags: servicenow

I want to print the elements from an array , using foreach loop it is giving error **"The prefix j for element j:foreach is not bound"**.

Below is the code which I wrote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<j:jelly trim="false" xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:j2="null" xmlns:g2="null">
<h1>Jello World </h1>

<g:evaluate>
    var words=['Hello','world','bye'];
</g:evaluate>

<j:foreach var="jvar_word" items="${words}">
    <p> ${jvar_word} </p>
</j:foreach>    

</j:jelly>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Jelly is case sensitive. Try changing `j:foreach` to `f:forEach`.

```
<j:forEach var="jvar_word" items="${words}">
    <p> ${jvar_word} </p>
</j:forEach>
```